# Unable to horizontally center items in ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Trying to center items in a `ColumnLayout` (nested into a `StackLayout`) but doesn't seem to work.

The `StackLayout` contains also a `Canvas` which I used to verify that `Layout.fillWidth: true` is working as expected. So I assume also the `ColumnLayout` is filling width (i.e. the problem is not the outer `StackLayout`), although I cannot understand what problem it has.

[image: Animation showing the problem]

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 340
    height: 380
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello")

    TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        width: parent.width
        TabButton {text: "Layout"}
        TabButton {text: "Canvas"}
    }
    
    StackLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: tabBar.height
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
        
        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            spacing: 10
            
            Label {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                text: "Regular buttons:"
            }
            
            RowLayout {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                spacing: 10
                Button {text: "Normal"}
                Button {text: "Highlighted"; highlighted: true}
                DelayButton {text: "Delay"}
            }
            
            Label {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                text: "Checkboxes:"
            }
            
            RowLayout {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                spacing: 10
                CheckBox {text: "Checkbox 1"}
                CheckBox {text: "Checkbox 2"}
            }
            
            Label {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                text: "Radiobuttons:"
            }
            
            RowLayout {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                spacing: 10
                RadioButton {text: "Radiobutton 1"}
                RadioButton {text: "Radiobutton 2"}
            }
            
            Label {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                text: "Miscellaneous:"
            }
            
            Switch {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                text: "Switch"
            }
        }
        
        Canvas {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.maximumHeight: 100
            Layout.margins: 2
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext('2d')
                ctx.reset()
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                ctx.lineWidth = 2
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
                ctx.lineTo(width, height)
                ctx.stroke()
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.moveTo(width, 0)
                ctx.lineTo(0, height)
                ctx.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After a lot of fiddling around, I discovered that the layout will resize correctly if it contains an item with `fillWidth`, so the problem is fixed if I add an `Item {Layout.fillWidth: true}` into the `ColumnLayout`

Comment: That same workaround is mentioned in this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60489).

Comment: I go back and forth as to whether it is a bug. It happens in the vertical dimension also with RowLayout. I think of it as the ColumnLayout is limited to growing to the sum of its items implicitWidths unless you set one of the children to fill. An empty Item is the perfect thing for that (although it results in additional `spacing` even though it is not visible).